# Can I use virtualbox to install Ubuntu Linux on Windows?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I wanted to use Linux, but keep Windows 8; so is it possible to have run both OS's on one PC?

Comment: -1 for no research effort. This is a very trivial question that can be answered in literally a few seconds using Google. It's literally the first result for "virtualbox ubuntu windows".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can totally run one or more Ubuntu guests in VirtualBox on a Windows host. To do that please follow the instructions in Ubuntu wiki: [Installing Virtualbox in Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox#Installing_Virtualbox_in_Windows).

Comment: okay cool, how could I install it? Are there any youtube videos or articles? Any youtube videos? Articles? You're Input is very useful

Comment: @BigUltra: I've added a link